# Having trouble with java regex

Tags: java, regex

I'm new to regex in Java and am having trouble getting it to work properly. The following code is saying there were no matches found.

```
pattern = Pattern.compile("EN\\( [ -][0-5]\\)= \\d+.?\\d*E[+-]\\d{2}");
match = pattern.matcher("EN(  0)= 0.000000E+00");
String result = match.group();
```

As far as I can tell, this should be working. I've been using the [Oracle java tutorial on regular expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/index.html) to guide me. Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: How is the code saying no matches were found?  Show the unexpected behavior or output.

Comment: I get a `No Match Found` error, being thrown by `match.group()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost there, you just need:

```
Matcher match = pattern.matcher("EN(  0)= 0.000000E+00");
match.find(); // <-- missing
String result = match.group();
```

Answer (score 1):

`-` in `[ -]` is special character so you must use `[ \\-]`

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("EN\\( [ \\-][0-5]\\)= \\d+.?\\d*E[+\\-]\\d{2}");
Matcher match = pattern.matcher("EN(  0)= 0.000000E+00");
if (match.find())
    System.out.println(match.group());
```